# Imagen (Image1) userform a hoja de excel

Tags: excel, macros

Buen día.

Saludos a todos, estoy realizando una pequeña macro en excel con vb-userform donde tengo varios campos de texto estos datos los paso a una hoja de excel mediante un boton.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta imagen quiero agregarlo en mi hoja. Estoy utilizando este código, los campos de texto si lo copia pero la imagen no.

```
 Private Sub cmdAgregar_Click()

Sheets("Formulario").Select

NR = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

Cells(NR + 1, 1) = txtModelo
Cells(NR + 1, 2) = txtTallaBase
Cells(NR + 1, 3) = txtCliente
Cells(NR + 1, 4) = txtFechaElaboracion
Cells(NR + 1, 5) = txtDescripcion
Cells(NR + 1, 6) = txtTemporada
Cells(NR + 1, 7) = txtEntrega
Cells(NR + 1, 121) = LoadPicture(Image1)

End Sub
```

La 121 es donde quiero mostrar la imagen y con LoadPicture(Image1), me arroja error 13, no coinciden los tipos.

Por medio de mi botón(Cargar) me permite agregar la imagen en la herramienta Image.

```
Private Sub cmdCargar_Click()
Public foto As Variant
foto = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:= _
"Imagen (*.gif;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp), *.gif;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp", _
Title:="Seleccionar imagen", MultiSelect:=False)

If foto = False Then
Exit Sub
End If

If Not IsEmpty(Image1.Picture) Then
Image1.Picture = Nothing
End If

Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(foto)
Image1.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeStretch
Image1.Width = 100
Image1.Height = 100
End Sub
```

Ahora en esta imagen cargada quiero copiar o enviarla a una celda de excel  `Cells(NR + 1, 121)`, que método podría utilizar alguna sugerencia.

Agradesco su apoyo.

Comment: ¿`LoadPicture` no espera el nombre de un archivo? ¿`Image1` es una ruta válida?

Comment: Entiendo que `LoadPicture` es un procedimiento o UDF aparte. ¿No puedes poner el código de ese procedimiento?

Comment: Podrías anexar el código de tu botón cargar, me imagino que es la usas para insertar la imagen en el PictureBox

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se me ocurre que hagas y que también lo verifiqué y funciona (en Excel 2016) es que saques tu variable `foto` afuera del evento de tu botón `cmdCargar` para que puedas usarlo en otras instancias, ya que lo único que hace es almacenar la ruta de la imagen que vas cargando.

y dentro de tu botón `cmdAgregar` lo mandas insertar con el siguiente código:

```
Cells(NR + 1, 121).Select
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (foto)
```

donde `foto` es la ruta de la imagen que has cargado en tu pictureBox anteriormente, espero te sirva.